# Вопрос по for в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for

Цикл `for` работает исключительно с числами и всё? По сути в него строку нельзя запихнуть разве что не преобразив её через `int` по примеру
`str = "Тут что-то есть"` и переделав её в
`str = int("Тут что-то есть")`

Comment: Нет... Он работает с любыми итерируемыми последовательностями. Если передадите строку, то на каждой итерации будет отдельный символ из неё.

Comment: А можете привести пример того, как Вы работаете с числами в цикле `for`? Для этого можете нажать кнопку [edit].

Comment: Прохожу просто поначалу уроки по python чтобы далее развиваться уже. Вот что там написано. Просто в Java и PHP с C++ можно передавать строки. Вот захотел спросить и в Python как оно работает. Просто тут нету цикла 'do while' и он по иному построен. Вот что было в уроке                           После ключевого слова for идет переменная int_var, которая хранит целые числа (название переменной может быть любое), затем ключевое слово in, вызов функции range() и двоеточие.

Comment: Это предложение из какой-то учебной методички? Дело в том, что функция `range` является генератором. Она возвращает последовательность целых чисел, и цикл for берёт на каждой итерации отдельное число из этой последовательности.

Comment: Вы можете передать строки, например так: `for symbol in 'Hello, World!'`, и всё будет работать. Имя переменной для итерирования (`symbol`) может быть произвольным.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

а учебник/справочник почитать? там же все написано

`for` работает с любым итерируемым объектом, т.е. объектом, который позволяет пройтись последовательно по своим элементам

```
for index in range(11, 100, 2):
```

пройдет по всем числам от 11 до 100 с шагом 2 и `index` - это будут числом

```
for letter in "Привет":
```

пройдет по всем буквам строки и `letter` будут строками (содержащими по 1 букве)

```
for elem in [1, 'приветик', None, True]:
```

пройдет по всем элементам списка и `elem` будет и числом и строкой и None и булевым типом

Answer (score 1):

`for` работает со списками, ...

```
for v in [0, 1, 'abc', 'def', False, True, [0, 1, 2]]:
    print(v)
```

> ```
> 0
> 1
> abc
> def
> False
> True
> [0, 1, 2]
> ```

... строками, ...

```
for c in 'abcd':
    print(c)
```

> ```
> a
> b
> c
> d
> ```

... кортежами, ...

```
for v in (0, 1, 'abc'):
    print(v)
```

> ```
> 0
> 1
> abc
> ```

... специальными последовательностями (`range`, `zip`, `map`, ...), ...

```
for v in range(1, 10, 2):
    print(v)
```

> ```
> 1
> 3
> 5
> 7
> 9
> ```

... генераторами, ...

```
for v in (i * i for i in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)):
    print(v)
```

> ```
> 1
> 4
> 9
> 16
> 25
> ```

... генераторами заданными функцией, ...

```
def cubes():
    for i in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
        yield i ** 3

for v in cubes():
    print(v)
```

> ```
> 1
> 8
> 27
> 64
> 125
> ```

... генераторами заданными объектом с методами `__iter__` и `__next__`, ...

```
class SquareRoots:
    def __init__(self):
        self._i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._i >= 5:
            raise StopIteration
        self._i += 1
        return self._i ** 0.5

for v in SquareRoots():
    print(v)
```

> ```
> 1.0
> 1.4142135623730951
> 1.7320508075688772
> 2.0
> 2.23606797749979
> ```

... генераторами заданными объектом с методом `__getitem__`, ...

```
class CubicRoots:
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i >= 8:
            raise IndexError
        return (i + 1) ** (1 / 3)

for v in iter(CubicRoots()):
    print(v)
```

> ```
> 1.0
> 1.2599210498948732
> 1.4422495703074083
> 1.5874010519681994
> 1.7099759466766968
> 1.8171205928321397
> 1.912931182772389
> 2.0
> ```

... и любыми другими [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

А с целыми числами `for` не работает:

```
for v in 42:
    print(v)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "for_samples.py", line 66, in <module>
>     for v in 42:
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Не *только* с числами, но с числами *тоже*.

Примеры:

```
>>> for i in 1, 5, 13:
...     print(i)
```

> ```
> 1
> 5
> 13
> ```

```
>>> for word in "book", "tree", "house":
...     print(word)
```

> ```
> book
> tree
> house
> ```

```
>>> for letter in "человек":
...     print(letter)
```

> ```
> ч
> е
> л
> о
> в
> е
> к
> ```

```
>>> for true_false in 5 < 7, 100 > 1000, 1 + 1 == 2:
...     print(true_false)
```

> ```
> True
> False
> True
> ```

```
>>> for anything in 7, "word", 5 > 7, {1, 2, 3}:
...     print(anything)
```

> ```
> 7
> word
> False
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```